# WP Query returning results even when $args are not met?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the below WP Query, there seems to be a slightly odd behaviour. When the criteria is met, the correct products are shown, however, if not products match the criteria, other products are shown, rather than having no results? I'm unsure why this might be, but I would assume it is something to do with the `tax_query` section. In short, what it is trying to retrieve is products from the current tag, that are NOT tagged as featured products (I have another query that targets featured products so this is to avoid duplication).

How can I ensure no results are shown if the $args are not met?

Thanks.

```
//Get current Tag
$currentTag = get_term_by('slug', $wp_query->get_queried_object()->slug, 'product_tag');

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'status' => 'publish',
  'fields' => 'ids', // Only return IDs
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'limit' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    // Only items from current product_cat
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms'    => $currentTag->term_id,
      'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    // AND are not featured
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
      'field'    => 'name',
      'terms'    => 'featured',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
  ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**EDIT:**

After some further research, it seems the problem is coming form another query further down the page. First, I perform 2 WP Queries as per the above, to retrieve different product types, and then merge these into a single array of ID's. Then, I perform the below wc_get_products() query to actually retrieve the product data. As you can see, the `include` arg states that only the ID's previously queried should be included, but it seems to ignore this when there are no matching products and instead revert to honour the `per_page` arg. Any way to avoid this and ensure they are excluded? Is there a way to 'exclude' anything that isn't in the `$mergedQueries`?

```
$productsData = wc_get_products(array(
    'include'           => $mergedQueries,
    'paginate'          => true,
    'page'              => $paged,
    'limit'             => 3,
    'orderby'           => 'post__in',
    'return'            => 'objects',
));
```

Comment: Did you verify it was actually _this_ query, that returned results in this case?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely this query. I have temporarily removed any others on the page. The same thing happens also if the tax argument is looking for 'product_cat' rather than 'product_tag'

Comment: So the `post_count` and `found_posts` properties of that exact query instance are not 0 then, yes?

Comment: Do the tax queries work as expected individually? Also, did you try printout out the SQL query to see if it looks right or identify where the problem might be happening, e.g. `echo $the_query->request;`

Comment: @CBroe - Hmm, that's odd. When I print the query out (with no matching products), the post count is 0. Where could these other 3 be coming from?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you are using to display the posts?

Comment: It probably performs a _different_ query somewhere, to be able to display some “default” products, if the search query did not return any results? That’s why I asked whether you had verified it was _this_ query returning the results in the first place, because that sounded impossible to begin with.

Comment: Question updated, discovered the problem is in another query as suspected.

Comment: Guess there might be some mechanism that ignores the `include` parameter, if an empty array is passed? I’d try and provide an array with a fake, non-existent ID then - `-1`, or PHP_INT_MAX maybe.

Comment: @CBroe - yes that's exactly what is happening. If I try the fake ID, nothing displays at all, as it's looking for just one product that doesn't exist. If I leave the $mergedQueries include, and change per_page to -1, it works correctly when a product exists in the array, otherwise just shows all products. It seems to me that there should be a way to include the array I have, and then exclude anything that isn't in this array?

Comment: _“If I try the fake ID, nothing displays at all”_ - isn’t that what you want?

Comment: I suppose I could add a fake ID to the $mergedArray, but just feels a bit hacky?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but is the last query only to get the product info for the results of the first 2 queries? So could you not just check the count of `mergedQueries` (or even `post_count`/`found_posts` for the first `WP_Query`s - I presume you have to check that anyway to merge the results?) and only run the second query if the results are > 0?

Comment: Good idea @FluffyKitten, does the job and feels a little less hacky